# Minimize Optimization on Two-Dimensional Matrix

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
z = Array[Subscript[y, ##] &, {3, 2}]
f = {2, 5, 1}
z*f
Total[Flatten[ z*f]]
Minimize[{Total[Flatten[ z*f]], 
  Total[z] == 10 && NonNegative[Min[z]]}, z, Integers]
```

The above code works for one-dimensional matrix z, But when z is two-dimensional, this error occurs:

```
Minimize::ivar: {Subscript[y, 1,1],Subscript[y, 1,2]} is not a valid variable. >>
```

Anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has to provide the variables as a flat list. Therefore you just have to replace `z` with `Flatten[z]` in your `Minimize`:

```
Minimize[{Total[Flatten[z*f]], Total[z] == 10 && NonNegative[Min[z]]}, Flatten@z, Integers]
```

> [image: Out]